# How do I find/fix: ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I have an app that reads large customer-supplied data files. It works perfectly with several but, on one file I received today, it is failing with:

```
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

I am using String.match to look for regex patterns.

When I look at the file, nothing seems different from the ones that work.

Advice?

Edit: it looks like there there is an 'xE9' character in a user name.

Comment: Did you look at any of the related questions on the right-hand side of the page? Try reading some of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[ruby]+invalid+byte+sequence

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374756/why-do-i-get-an-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8-error-reading-a-text-file?rq=1

Comment: I did. Nothing seemed to apply--to me at least. I am just reading a text file line by line.

Comment: A `'\xE9'` character suggests that you have an ISO 8859-1 file that you're treating as UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort. I've never encountered anything like this. Can you tell me what I should do?

Comment: You could open the file with the appropriate encoding and then use `String#encode` to switch to UTF-8. For example, if you start with ISO 8859-1 (`s = "\xE9".force_encoding('iso8859-1')`) and then switch to UTF-8 (`s.encode!('utf-8')`) then you'll get the `é` that you're looking for. There are tons of encoding questions kicking around so I'll just leave this as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @muistooshort 's help, I opened the file in ISO mode and then, reading line by line, convert to UTF-8.

```
myfile = File.open( 'thefile.txt', 'r:iso8859-1' )
  while rawline = myfile.gets
  line = rawline.force_encoding( 'utf-8' )
  # proceed...
end
```

Comment: Not saying this is the ideal solution but it seems simple enough and totally resolved my issue on multiple affected data files.

Answer (score -1):

A little rake job that illustrates the solution:

```
task :reencode, [:filename] => [:environment] do |t, args|
  myfile = File.open( args[:filename], 'r:iso8859-1' )
  outfile = File.open( args[:filename] + ".out", "w+" )
  while rawline = myfile.gets
    line = rawline.force_encoding( 'utf-8' )
    outfile.write line
  end 
  outfile.close
end
```